# How to list all GitHub users?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm working on a site, need to crawl all user information (at least the user on our site) from GitHub. I searched GitHub API, and found no answer.

So is there any way I can do this job? 
I only have the users emails. (I can check user by compare the email hash with gravatar URL)

1. I had send email to GitHub support, and got no answer currently.
2. I only need know the usernames, I can use GitHub API to get other informations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As described [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/) you may rely on those two following APIs to retrieve a JSON formatted output. As requested, both of them provide the gravatar URL.

**Collaborators** (members of the organization on the project)

- *syntax:* repos/show/:user/:repo/collaborators [GET]
- *example:* https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/collaborators

**Contributors** (authors of, at least, one commit)

- *syntax:* repos/show/:user/:repo/contributors [GET]
- *example:* https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/contributors

---

**UPDATE:**

The previous API methods requires that you start from a *known* repository.
The two following proposals try to work around this constraint. They rely on the [previous version of the API (v2)](https://developer.github.com/)

**Query by email** (in your question, you state *"I only have the users emails."*. Provided the users agreed to publish them you should be able to retreive some information about the user using the email as a query parameter)

- *syntax:* /api/v2/xml/user/email/:email [GET]
- *example:* https://github.com/api/v2/xml/user/email/tom@github.com

**Search for repositories** (given some keywords (language, stack, ...) retrieve a list of repositories. Then, for each one, using the two first proposals, list their collaborators and/or contributors)

- *syntax:* /api/v2/json/repos/search/:here+go+your+keywords [GET]
- *example:* https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/search/stackoverflow

**Note:** Make sure that intended usage of the API is in concordance with **[GitHub Terms of service](http://help.github.com/terms-of-service/)**

Comment: @linjunhalida I've updated my answer with some proposals/workarounds.

Answer (score 7):

**GitHub Archive**

https://www.githubarchive.org/

This project can be used to quickly get a dump of all usernames who have ever done anything public.

It exports the GitHub events API to a Google BigQuery dataset frequently.

The data format starting from 2015 is:

```
SELECT
    actor.login
FROM (
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE([githubarchive:day.events_],
        TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01'),
        TIMESTAMP('2015-01-02')
    ))
GROUP BY actor.login
ORDER BY actor.login
```

and there is more data starting from 2011-02-12 in a different format, should be easy to figure it out.

Downloading the data takes some fighting with Google BigQuery but is doable: [How to download all data in a Google BigQuery dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493533/google-bigquery-download-all-data/37274820#37274820)

I have used a similar method to extract all GitHub commit emails at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/all-github-commit-emails

Answer (score 5):

`https://api.github.com/search/users?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}`

Please check https://developer.github.com/v3/search/ for more details

Comment: what are the values for `sort` and `order` ?

Comment: `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=TEST`

Comment: @Hemang all reported in the docs:)

Answer (score 2):

Note that since May 2013, you now can extract a lot more information from a repository.
See "[File CRUD and repository statistics now available in the API](https://github.com/blog/1498-file-crud-and-repository-statistics-now-available-in-the-api)"

> We're using the repository statistics API to power our [graphs](https://github.com/github/linguist/graphs), but we can't wait to see what others do with this information.
>
> Starting today, these resources are available to you:

- [Contributors](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-contributors-list-with-additions-deletions-and-commit-counts)
- [Commit Activity](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-the-last-year-of-commit-activity-data)
- [Code Frequency](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-the-number-of-additions-and-deletions-per-week)
- [Participation](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-the-weekly-commit-count-for-the-repo-owner-and-everyone-else)
- [Punch Card](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-the-number-of-commits-per-hour-in-each-day)

Answer (score 2):

Team wise list the users:-

```
curl -H "Authorization: token [yours]" https://api.github.com/user/teams
```

With the following cmd, you can list all the users of github.

```
curl -H "Authorization: token fkslsml4442323wdsfsdf" https://api.github.com/orgs/cloudaws/members?page=1 | grep login >> github.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably like to checkout this post - https://github.com/blog/643-contributors

The api call can be made like this:

`http://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/show/<user>/<repository-name>/contributors`