# Getting all GitHub users through github-api

Tags: github-api

The GitHub API documentation says that the url

https://api.github.com/users

will give all users in the order they signed up, but I only seem to get the first 135.

Any ideas how to get the real full list?

Comment: Git != Github, is not the "git api" is the "github api", I'll edit your question, but thought it was pertinent to point out the difference too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all GitHub users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329978/how-to-list-all-github-users)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please use `since` parameter in your GET request.

```
https://api.github.com/users?since=XXX
```

Probably it's done this way to limit the resources needed to handle such request. Without such limit it's just asking for [DoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack.

Answer (score 4):

If you check the response headers for that request Github provides pagination links under the header `Links`

```
Link: <https://api.github.com/users?since=135>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/users{?since}>; rel="first"
```

I believe since their api `v3` Github has been moving towards a hypermedia api.

[Github Hypermedia API](http://developer.github.com/v3/#hypermedia)

**EDIT**

This is beyond the scope of this question but its related. To learn more about hypermedia API and REST. Take a look at these slides by Steve Klabnik

http://steveklabnik.github.com/hypermedia-presentation/#1

Answer (score 2):

Both of the existing answers are 100% correct, but I would advise you to use a wrapper for whatever language you happen to be doing this in. There are plenty of them and there is an official one for ruby (Octokit). Here is a [list](http://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/) of all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter on [`type:user`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-users#search-only-users-or-organizations) like this:

```
https://api.github.com/search/users?q=type:user
```

**See Also**: [GitHub API get total number of users/organizations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47502683/1366033)