# GitHub API get total number of users/organizations

Tags: github, github-api

Using [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3), how can I count the total number of users/organizations at the time of the request?

[Users](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/) and [Organizations](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/) API responses do not contain `last` [Link header](https://developer.github.com/v3/#link-header).

**Note**: Following `next` Link header until the last one, is not a solution for me because of the [rate limits](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) for a free account.

Comment: Are you using authenticated requests? Those should give you 5000 requests per hour whether you're on a free or paid plan.

Comment: Even with 5000 request per hour, the maximum number of items per page is 100, that will do 5000*100=500000 which seems lower that the total of existing organizations. Am I right?

Comment: Not at the moment. Bertrand's answer below is pretty great, if all you're looking for is the counts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### GraphQL API v4

You can get user count & organization count using [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) :

```graphql
{
  user: search(type: USER, query: "type:user") {
    userCount
  }
  org: search(type: USER, query: "type:org") {
    userCount
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?variables=%7B%7D&query=%7B%0A%20%20user%3A%20search(type%3A%20USER%2C%20query%3A%20%22type%3Auser%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20userCount%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20org%3A%20search(type%3A%20USER%2C%20query%3A%20%22type%3Aorg%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20userCount%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

which gives :

```json
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "userCount": 24486303
    },
    "org": {
      "userCount": 1629433
    }
  }
}
```

#### REST API v3

- search query with `type:user` : https://api.github.com/search/users?q=type%3Auser
- search query with `type:org` : https://api.github.com/search/users?q=type%3Aorg

The result gives `total_count` field with the required value

It matches the result you can find using Github search :

- for user : https://github.com/search?q=type%3Auser&type=Users&utf8=%E2%9C%93
- for org : https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=type%3Aorg&type=Users

Comment: Worked for me. For an enterprise hosted, the only change is making the url: `https://myorg.coolorg.dev/api/v3/search/users?` for the beginning.