# Github Enterprise activate dormant users

Tags: github, github-enterprise

I am using Github Enterprise v2.13.5 and want to activate dormant users. Currently Github automatically activates the dormant user when they log back in. But I need to explicitly activate all dormant users

Comment: Did you find a solution already @vabhihav-n?

Answer (score 0):

The `/users` API does not tell us whether a User is dormant or not. There are some manual [workarounds](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-get-the-GitHub-dormant-users-report-from-a-command-line-tool) for at least identifying the inactive users , but most that I found are not feasible in practice.

If you do not need any information on which user was dormant, you could write a little script that automatically creates impersonation tokens for each user and (in their name) do one arbitrary action on Github:

1. With your account, create a project `[yourname]/un-dormant-project`
2. For each known user (get via [`/users` API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796304/getting-all-github-users-through-github-api)):

   a. Create an [impersonation token](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.14/v3/enterprise-admin/users/#create-an-impersonation-oauth-token)

   b. In the name of the user, perform an arbitrary action on `[yourname]/un-dormant-project`

   c. Delete impersonation token

I assume that you must not delete the project you created because otherwise the users will become dormant again very quickly.

Disclaimer: I did not try this approach out.