# BigQuery - Export query results to local file/Google storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I want to export query results from BigQuery to local file/Google storage.

I tried 'bq extract' command but it doesn't allow query as input.

```
Usage: bq extract <source_table> <destination_uris>
```

I don't want to extract the whole table as the table contains many columns which are not required and I need to aggregate the data.

As of now, the only workaround I could find is to create a table using the 'bq query' command and use the 'bq extract' to extract the data.

I'm looking for any better way to achieve this by doing something like below.

```
bq extract 'select dept_id,sum(sal) from temp.employee 
                                 group by dept_id' 'gs://XXXX/employee.csv'
```

Answer (score 23):

Direct export from BigQuery Standard SQL was added recently: [Exporting data to csv format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#exporting_data_to_csv_format)

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://mybucket/myfolder2/*.csv',
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=true,
  field_delimiter=';') AS
SELECT 1 as field1, 2 as field2
```

Comment: Is it possible to have dynamic uri? say folder/file name with currentdate suffix.

Comment: update: I am able to have an expression for uri by defining a variable and wrapping up the whole content as a stored procedure.

Answer (score 8):

You can export it using the [EXPORT DATA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_data_statement)  which can enable writing query results directly to GCS, like

```
EXPORT DATA

[WITH CONNECTION connection_name]

OPTIONS (export_option_list) AS

query_statement
```

or using the Web UI in just three steps

1. Configure query to save the results in a BigQuery table and run it.
2. Export the table to a bucket in GCS.
3. Download from the bucket.

### Step 1

When in BigQuery screen, before running the query go to More > Query Settings

[image: Configure Query]

This opens the following

[image: Query Settings]

Here you want to have

- Destination: Set a destination table for query results
- Project name: select the project.
- Dataset name: select a dataset. If you don't have one, create it and come back.
- Table name: give whatever name you want (must contain only letters, numbers, or underscores).
- Result size: Allow large results (no size limit).

Then Save it and the Query is configured to be saved in a specific table. Now you can run the Query.

### Step 2

To export it to GCP you have to go to the table and click EXPORT > Export to GCS.

[image: BigQuery export table]

This opens the following screen

[image: Export to GCS]

In **Select GCS location** you define the bucket, the folder and the file.

For instances, you have a bucket named *daria_bucket* (*Use only lowercase letters, numbers, hyphens (-), and underscores (_). Dots (.) may be used to form a valid domain name.*) and want to save the file(s) in the root of the bucket with the name *test*, then you write (in Select GCS location)

```
daria_bucket/test.csv
```

If the file is too big (more than 1 GB), you'll get an error. To fix it, you'll have to save it in more files using wildcard. So, you'll need to add *, just like that

```
daria_bucket/test*.csv
```

[image: Wildcard export to GCS]

This is going to store, inside of the bucket daria_bucket, all the data extracted from the table in more than one file named test000000000000, test000000000001, test000000000002, ... testX.

### Step 3

Then go to Storage and you'll see the bucket.

[image: GCS bucket]

Go inside of it and you'll find the one (or more) file(s). You can then download from there.

Answer (score 6):

BigQuery does not provide ability to directly export/download query result to GCS or Local File. First you need to get result of query either in explicitly set destination table or if not set you can use temp (anonymous) table that  holds query result - you can get it (table) from respective job attribute [`configuration.query.destinationTable`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.destinationTable) (after job is completed)
Then you can use that table as a source for Export job

Comment: Can you please add more details on how to use the temp table using bq command

Comment: This is not quite true. You can save query results to a local file `bq query --format=csv --max_rows=9999 --use_legacy_sql=false "SELECT * FROM dataset.table;" > result.csv`. This would work for small-medium size results. But not great for queries that return gigabytes of data.

Comment: @Igor-S  -  the question was explicitly about **extract** so the answers here were mostly focusing on this aspect. so the whole point here is exactly the same as actually in your answer - you can query and then manipulate result in a different ways. your answer uses   `bq query ... > file.ext` which is also legit. but above (mine) and other answers saying No for extract are still correct :o)

Answer (score 5):

You can always use bash scripts for things that are not supported by gcloud cli.
For example you can dump query results into a file:

```
bq query --format=csv --max_rows=999999 --use_legacy_sql=false\
  "select dept_id,sum(sal) from temp.employee group by dept_id" > employee.csv
```

And then you can just upload it to cloud storage:

```
gsutil mv employee.csv 'gs://XXXX/employee.csv'
```

Answer (score 3):

These days (till they change the console again) you can achieve this by

```
1_ run your query   
2_ when it is completed, then you can use "Save the result" dropdown
to save it in a *local/cloud* file.
```

Be advised this option is not supported on command-line or API call at the moment :-)

Answer (score 2):

Filtering for export is not supported.
You can store result of query as another temp table and export this table so it will be two step process.

Comment: Can you please add more details on how to use the temp table using bq command

Answer (score 2):

As @MikhailBerlyan points out, you need an intermediate table. You can do it by using the BigQuery UI:

- Run the query for filtering ('select dept_id,sum(sal) from temp.employee group by dept_id' in your case).
- Once the query is done click on `Save as->Save as table`. This step creates the intermediate table with the filtering done.
- Open that table, and on the right most side click on `Export->Export to GCS`.

Here is the documentation for [exporting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data).

Comment: the UI has changed, there is no `save as table` anymore. Also note that you have to have the right permissions enabled, or this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

My company has not subscribed to google drive, so we use this workaround -

1. Run the query in BQ Query editor.
2. Click on `Save Query Results` and select `Bigquery Table` from `Choose where to save the results data from the query` dropdown.
3. Select the project name, dataset name, and provide a table name e.g data_dump_13_jan and click on save.
4. Depending on the data set, it might take a few seconds to a few hours.
5. Once the job is done, go to the cloud shell terminal and run the following command.

`bq --location=<your GCP Zone> --destination_format CSV <dataset-id>:<table-name> gs://<gcp-bucket>/<dump-file-name>.csv`