# Is it possible to export a BigQuery query into equal 5000-line CSV files in GCS bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I'm aware of the ability to export a query to CSV files in a GCS Bucket; however, when exporting to multiple files there doesn't seem to be a way to limit the row count of each file. I was wondering if anyone has figured out a workaround to allow for this functionality. My current use-case is I need to export a query of a table (152 columns) into multiple CSV files, saving them to a GCS bucket. Each file can't have more than 5000 records. I was hoping to find some sort of statement I could pop into BigQuery to avoid having to write a solution in python (since this is a short-term requirement and won't be needed after a certain point).

I came up with the following pseudo-SQL-code:

```
offset = 0
total = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WEB_SCRAPING.scrapy_products WHERE spider = "{​0}​"
while offset < total + 5000:
    EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
        uri='gs://webscraping/{​0}​_{offset}-{offset + 5000}.csv',
        format='CSV',
        overwrite=true,
        header=true
    ) AS (
        SELECT * EXCEPT (id)
        FROM WEB_SCRAPING.scrapy_products
        WHERE spider = "{0}"
        LIMIT 5000 OFFSET {offset};
    )
    offset += 5000
```

I was thinking that I could somehow wrap the `EXPORT DATA` statement in a CASE statement that loops, incrementing the offset until all results are exported. But, from what I've seen the `EXPORT DATA` statement requires an asterisk, which will likely lead to the 5000-record chunks being split into even smaller files.

Any idea on how I can make this work from a BigQuery SQL standpoint? Is it even possible?

---

**Update:** Here's what I have so far as BigQuery statement

```sql
DECLARE spider STRING DEFAULT 'albertsons.albertsons';
DECLARE increment INT64 DEFAULT 5000;

DECLARE tt_name STRING;
DECLARE `offset` INT64;
DECLARE total INT64;

SET `offset` = 0;
SET total = (SELECT COUNT(*) as total_products FROM `WEB_SCRAPING.SCRAPY_PRODUCTS` WHERE spider = FORMAT('"%s"', spider));

WHILE offset < (total + increment) DO
  SET tt_name = FORMAT("`WEB_SCRAPING.%s_%dto%d`", @spider, @offset, @`offset` + @increment);
  CREATE TEMP TABLE tt_name AS (
    SELECT * EXCEPT (id)
    FROM `WEB_SCRAPING.SCRAPY_PRODUCTS`
    WHERE spider = FORMAT('"%s"', @spider)
    LIMIT @increment OFFSET @`offset`
  );
  
  -- Now, to just handle the export portion
  
  SET `offset` = @`offset` + @increment;
END WHILE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this only with SQL code. You need to create your temp table as you did and then to iterate over them (in python or other languages) to extract the table to file with the [extract API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data)

Answer (score 0):

As it was commented before, you can't export BQ data using only SQL code. In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651171/export-bigquery-data-to-csv-without-using-google-cloud-storage) the community mentioned some workarounds of how to export data  from BQ.

I recommend you using the [`extract_table`](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/81df4ba518dd82d6ef2519adb7803d4c90119a8b/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L2749) function which belongs to the [BQ Extract API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#python). This API is able to export the data into [multiple files](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files) using the single wildcard URI (used for exported data that will be larger than the 1 GB maximum value). With this, BQ shards your data into multiple files based on the provided pattern. The size of the exported files will vary.

I have created a test using a public dataset which table size is 4.58 GB, it has 33,319,019 rows and 15 columns

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
bucket_name = "[BUCKET_NAME]"
project = "bigquery-public-data"
dataset_id = "new_york"
table_id = "citibike_trips"


def exporting_data():
    destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, "citibike_*.csv")
    dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

    extract_job = client.extract_table(
        table_ref,
        destination_uri,
        # Location must match that of the source table.
        location="US",
    )  # API request
    extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

    print(
        "Exported {}:{}.{} to {}".format(project, dataset_id, table_id, destination_uri)
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    exporting_data()
```

After running this code, 49 files were exported to the bucket `[BUCKET_NAME]`. The size of every file is around 98 MB with aproximately 600 000 rows. Please consider creating temporal tables to export the desired data.